# PHP if/else based on parameter being true

Tags: php

This is part of the PHP that is outputting HTML from a function I'm working on. I'm getting stuck on the if/else state where I need to check if a parameter is set to true or false.

If it's set to true, I have HTML I want to output, if it's false, nothing needs to happen.

```
<?php
/**
 * 
*
* @param array $settings
*
* @return string
*/

function PCStandardTextBlock( $settings = array() ) {

//---- Get Settings ----
//The functions default settings will be merged with what's passed in.

$settingsDefault = array(
    'small_heading' => '',
    'large_heading' => '',
    'text' => '',
    'text_mode' => 'basic', //or advanced
    'big_first_p' => false,
    'link_url' => '', 
    'link_text' => '',
    'link_new_tab' => false,
    'link_style' => 'action_link', //or button
    'photo' => '', //cloudinary id
    'image_alt_text' => '',
    'crop_gravity' => 'face',
    'icon' => '', //icn-class
    'color_scheme' => 'white', //or accent1, accent2, accent4
    'container_id' => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'special_feature' => 'camplife_links', //or link_modal, hidden_content
    'modal_id' => '',
    'hidden_content_location' => 'another_block', //or in_this_block (see day-camps.php)
    'hidden_text' => '',
    'hidden_content_id' => '',
);

$settings = array_merge($settingsDefault, $settings);


//---- Set Variables ----
//These will allow the markup buildup to be as clean as possible.

$has_photo = strlen($settings['photo']) > 0;
$has_icon = strlen($settings['icon']) > 0;
$has_small_heading = strlen($settings['small_heading']) > 0;
$has_image_alt_text = strlen($settings['image_alt_text']) > 0;

//Note to Sal: If text mode is basic, wrap it in a <p> tag, if advanced, don't.

//If container_id is set, prepare the attribute
$has_container_id = strlen($settings['container_id']) > 0;
$possible_container_id_attribute = ($has_container_id) ? " id='{$settings['container_id']}'" : "";

//Handle the color scheme setting
switch( $settings['color_scheme'] ) {
case 'accent1': // blue
  $gcol_color_class = 'bg-color-accent1-C';
        $small_heading_color_class = 'color-white';
        $icon_color_class = 'color-white';
  break;

    case 'accent2': // green
  $gcol_color_class = 'bg-color-accent2-C';
        $small_heading_color_class = 'color-white';
        $icon_color_class = 'color-white';
  break;

case 'accent4': // yellow
  $gcol_color_class = 'bg-color-accent4-D';
        $small_heading_color_class = 'color-accent1-9';
        $icon_color_class = 'color-accent1-9';
  break;

    default; //white
        $gcol_color_class = ''; // empty
        $small_heading_color_class = 'color-base-A';
        $icon_color_class = 'color-accent1-9';
}

// Handle the special feature setting
switch( $settings['special_feature']) {

    case 'camplife_links':
        $special_feature_display = '<div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="gcol">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pine-cove-camplife/id991165025?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4">
                    <img class="width-100" src="/images/logos/badges/app-store-badge.png" alt="Download on the App Store" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="gcol">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinecove.camplife">
                    <img class="width-100" src="/images/logos/badges/google-play-badge.png" alt="Get it on Google Play" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>';
        break;

    default; // don't show anything
    $special_feature_display = ''; // Empty
}

$has_special_feature = strlen( $settings['special_feature'] ) > 0;

// Settings to call PCResponsiveImage with output set to false to save the results to a variable for inclusion in the output

$responsive_image_settings = array(
    'cloudinary_ID' => $settings['photo'],
    'aspect_ratios' => '1x1',
    'crop_gravity' => $settings['crop_gravity'],
    'screen_portion' => 'partial',
    'style_profile' => 'style4',
    'output' => false,
);

// If image alt text has been set, us it, otherwise don't set anything so responsive image can do it's thing (it sets the alt text to the filename).

if ( $has_image_alt_text ) {
    $responsive_image_settings['alt_text'] = $settings['image_alt_text'];
}

//Save PCResponsiveImage markup to a variable

$responsive_image_html = PCResponsiveImage( $responsive_image_settings );


//---- Build Output ----
//Line by line, concatenating strings with new line and tab characters.
$output  = "\n<!-- Standard Text Block -->";
$output .= "\n<div class='gcol-md-1-2 {$gcol_color_class} {$settings['container_class']}'{$possible_container_id_attribute}>";
$output .= "\n\t<div class='padbox-standard-content'>";

if( $has_photo ) {
        $output .= "\n\t<div class='small-heading-image'>";
        $output .= "\n\t\t{$responsive_image_html}";
        $output .= "\n\t</div>";
} elseif( $has_icon ) {
    $output .= "<span class='icn {$settings['icon']} $icon_color_class width-90'></span>";
}

if( $has_small_heading ) {
    $output .= "\n\t<h1 class='small-heading $small_heading_color_class'>{$settings['small_heading']}</h1>";
}

$output .= "\n\t<h2 class='heading-extended'>{$settings['large_heading']}</h2>";

if ( $settings['text_mode'] == 'basic' ) {
$output .= "\n\t\t\t\t<p>{$settings['text']}</p>"; // basic version
} elseif ( $settings['big_first_p'] === true ) {
    $output .= "\n\t\t\t\t<p class='big-p'>{$settings['text']}</p>";
}   else {
    $output .= "\n\t\t\t\t{$settings['text']}"; // advanced text mode; not big-p
}

if( $has_special_feature ) {
    $output .= "\n\t\t\t$special_feature_display";
}

$output .= "\n\t</div><!-- END padbox-standard-content -->";
$output .= "\n</div><!-- END gcol-md-1-2 -->";

//---- Return Output ----
return $output;
}
```

This is the function on the page where it calls the function (I've left off some parameters in the function call above to save space):

```
<?php echo PCStandardTextBlock(
            array(
                'small_heading' => 'Small Heading',
                'large_heading' => 'Large Heading',
                'text' => 'This is example text that is just basic text. If this was advanced text, then it would be multiple paragraphs.',
                'text_mode' => 'basic',
                'big_first_p' => true,
                'photo' => '', 
                'image_alt_text' => '',
                'icon' => '', 
                'color_scheme' => 'white',
                'special_feature' => '', 
                'container_id' => '',
                'container_class' => '',
            )
        ); ?>
```

Comment: Which parameter are you checking? You are checking two in the code above.

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? Questions about code should generally include the desired/expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how the two are different if you want to get helpful answers.

Comment: Your settings array is called `settingsDefault`, in your if-else statements, you are using something else as `settings`. Did you check that first?

Comment: I updated the code, sorry. I only pulled part of the whole function for this question.

Comment: @SalB What do you want your code to look like when it is functioning correctly? Besides the `settingsDefault` and `settings` I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @blackandorangecat it should output the <p class="big-p">text</p>. When I echo the function out on my test, it's just outputting the normal <p>text</p>

Comment: @SalB You do see that you don't have an array named `settings` right?

Comment: We need to know what your `$settings` variable looks like, since you have string keys the values from `$settings` will overwrite what's in `$settingsDefault` when the keys are the same http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Please show us the `var_dump($settings);`, before or after the `array_merge` call.  My guess is you don't have anything in `$settings['text_mode']` so the default is taking precedence and `if ( $settings['text_mode'] == 'basic' )` is evaluating to true

Comment: @kjones added more of the full function. Trying not to paste the entire thing .. it's yuge.

Comment: No problem if it's too big, but we need to know what the value of `$settings['text_mode']` is specifically before the `array_merge` call.  If it's not set, we can see it will use the default and the first if block will be executed.

Comment: @kjones full function added

Comment: I updated my answer, your code is functioning correctly.  When you call your function just change the `'text_mode' => 'basic',` line in the settings array to something like `'text_mode' => 'not-basic',` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were checking a non-existent array key: `$settings['big_first_p']`.  Here it is corrected:

```
$settingsDefault = array(
  'big_first_p' => false,
);

if ( $settingsDefault['text_mode'] == 'basic' ) {
  $output .= "\n\t\t\t\t<p>{$settings['text']}</p>"; // basic version
} elseif ( $settingsDefault['big_first_p'] === true ) {
  $output .= "\n\t\t\t\t<p class='big-p'>{$settings['text']}</p>";
} else {
  $output .= "\n\t\t\t\t{$settings['text']}"; 
}
```

Update:

So, you are passing in `'text_mode' => 'basic',`, which is why the basic version is getting appended to `$output` in your `if/elseif/else` statement.  Your code is functioning correctly.

If you want the `big-p` class one to be chosen, you need to place that block first in your `if/elseif/else` clause, or change the `text_mode` value you are passing into the function initially to something other than `'basic'`.

Comment: What is the `$settings` variable set to prior to using it in your `array_merge` line?

Comment: Thanks @kjones didn't realize the order of those if/elsif/else would affect it

Comment: Welcome, glad you got it sorted